# Passing arrays as method parameters in Java

Tags: java

The following code uses simple arrays of String in Java.

```
package javaarray;

final public class Main
{
    public void someMethod(String[] str)
    {
        System.out.println(str[0]+"\t"+str[1]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] str1 = new String[] {"day", "night"};
        String[] str2 = {"black", "white"};

        //Both of the above statements are valid.

        Main main=new Main();
        main.someMethod(str1);
        main.someMethod(str2);

        //We can invoke the method someMethod by supplying both of the above arrays alternatively.

        main.someMethod(new String[] { "day", "night" }); //This is also valid as obvious.
        main.someMethod({ "black", "white" }); //This is however wrong. The compiler complains "Illegal start of expression not a statement" Why?
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, we can initialize arrays like this.

```
String[] str1 = new String[] {"day", "night"};
String[] str2 = {"black", "white"};
```

and we can directly pass it to a method without being assigned like this.

```
main.someMethod(new String[] { "day", "night" });
```

If it is so, then the following statement should also be valid.

```
main.someMethod({ "black", "white" });
```

but the compiler complains "Illegal start of expression not a statement" Why?

Comment: I guess you somehow need to pass the reference of the string array. By what you are doing, that does not happen.

Comment: It might be hard to parse properly in the form you want, for example if the compiler sees `{1, 12, 57}`, what should it be -- a `byte[]`, `short[]`, `int[]`, or `long[]`? With the explicit type, the ambiguity is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Java Language Specification ([10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6))

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), creating an array and providing some initial values:

So, there are only two ways you can use an array initializer (`{"foo", "bar"}`):

1. Variable declaration: `String[] foo = {"foo", "bar"};`
2. Array creation expression: `new String[] {"foo", "bar"};`

You can't use an array initializer as a method parameter.

[15.10. Array Creation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)

```
ArrayCreationExpression:
    new PrimitiveType DimExprs Dimsopt
    new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs Dimsopt
    new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
    new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer
```

Comment: You don't mean `can't use it only ...`, do you?

Comment: In this sentence `So, you can use it only as a part of array creation expression` can I know you are referring to `it` as?

Comment: @noMAD, `it` is an array initializer. I'll try to improve my answer, though.

Comment: Please include the JLS link so that it may also be more helpful to future visitors.